# background image and repeating from folder image

Tags: css, background-image, background-repeat

I am trying to add a background from an image. The image is in a folder in my project named Images.
This is the code I am using but the screen remains white.

```
background-image:url("/Images/main-background.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

any help pls ?

Comment: Try This: background-image:url("../Images/main-background.png");

Comment: This is so your configuration and directory structure dependent... The css looks correct. Your path is probably broken, or your image blank :).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

if your folder resides on the same location where your page saved then try this

background-image:url("images/main-background.png");

to go back to the directory you can use ../ this can take you one step back.